# What does free do to a pointer passed by value to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

It is known that if we pass a pointer by value to a function, it cannot be freed inside the function, like so:

```
void func(int *p)
{
    free(p);
    p = NULL;
}
```

p holds a copy of a (presumably valid) address, so free(p) tries to, well, free it. But since it is a copy, it cannot really free it. How does the call to free() know that it cannot really free it ?

The code above does not produce an error. Does that mean free() just fails silently, "somehow" knowing that address passed in as argument cannot be worked upon ?

Comment: eh... that would work just fine. Of course the pointer passed in to the function would not be NULL, but the memory would be free'd.

Comment: StackOverflow Rule of Thumb #3: If the OP says "It is known", it is not.

Comment: Wouldn't the memory be freed, but to set the original pointer to null, you would need the address of the pointer itself and not a copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> p holds a copy of a (presumably valid) address, so free(p) tries to, well, free it. But since it is a copy, it cannot really free it.

It's not true. `free()` can work just fine if `p` is a valid address returned by `malloc()` (or `NULL`).

In fact, this is a common pattern for implementing custom "destructor" functions (when writing OO-style code in C).

What you probably mean is that `p` won't change to `NULL` after this - but that's natural, since you're passing it by value. If you want to `free()` **and** null out the pointer, then pass it by pointer ("byref"):

```
void func(int **p)
{
    if (p != NULL) {
        free(*p);
        *p = NULL;
    }
}
```

and use this like

```
int *p = someConstructor();
func(&p);
// here 'p' will actually be NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is if this function is in a different DLL (Windows). Then, it may be linked with a different version of the standard library and have different ideas on how the heap is built.

Otherwise no problem.

Comment: What do you mean, not at all?

Comment: Oh, but it is - I also explained why.

Comment: No, sorry, it's incorrect. The version of the standard library has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You can say "it is incorrect" any number of times and it does not change anything. Please re-read my answer to learn how standard library version matters, and you will be able to avoid a dangerous pitfall that hurt many amateurs.

Answer (score 2):

Passing `p` to `func()` by value, which will copy the pointer and creates the local copy to `func()` which frees the memory. `func()` then sets it's own instance of the pointer `p` to `NULL` but which is useless. Once the function is complete the parameter `p` come to end of existence. In calling function you still have pointer `p` holding an address, but the block is now on the free list and not useful for storage until allocated again.

Answer (score 1):

What everybody is saying is that your memory will be freed by `free(p);`, but your original pointer (which you use to call the function with) will still hold the (now invalid) address. If a new block of memory including your address is allocated at a later stage than your original pointer will become valid (for memory manager) again, but will now point to completely different data causing all sorts of problems and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

No you really free the block of memory. After the function call, the pointer passed to this function is pointing to nowhere : same address but the MMU don't know anymore what to do with this address